# Callback to execute when a thread is finished

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, callback

**Disclaimer (fully editable/removable)**

*I've done my homework but to the best of my recognition, I can't see the very thing I'd like to know (which is a bit surprising, so I'm sure that a kind soul will flag me as a duplicate - please accept my apology in advance, haha).*

**Background and anticipated issue**

When I start Outlook, I'm performing an update from CRM Dynamics, which takes a while. So, I decided to put the update in a thread. It works as supposed to **but** there's a button on the ribbon allowing a user to manually call for an update. Anticipating a frantic user, I realize that someone **will** click the button **before** the original update is finished and all kinds of excrement may hit the gas redistributive device.

**Suggested solution**

In order to avoid that, I've put a private property as follows.

```
private bool KeepYourPantsOn { get; set; }
```

As long as the said property is `true` (which it is set to right before I start the updating thread), all the frantic clicking will be either ignored or treated by a calm and informative

```
MessageBox.Show("Yes, yes... Updating still... Keep your pants on.");
```

but as soon as the thread is done, I'd like the property to flip over to `false` enabling the user to manually update Outlook.

**Implementation problem**

My hick-up is that I haven't found any `OnFinished`, `WhenDone` etc. method to call in order to switch the value of `KeepYourPantsOn`. Moreover, I haven't really seen any suggested solution on how to resolve that (or, rather - I haven't **perceived** any solution - I might have seen one without realizing that was it, due to ignorance within the area of threaded programming).

Comment: ??  Can you not just set the bool to false as the last line in your thread, (or as the last line before looping back to wait on something, if your thread does that).

Comment: BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted jumps to mind.

Comment: You'd probably need that boolean to be `volatile` in any case...

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure. Can I? I was assuming that the thread was its own realm and couldn't "touch" the instantiating object nor its members (except for the callback method). But your idea might just work. Put it as an answer so I can green-check you (and maybe give you arrow up, unless you're aiming at Unsung Hero).

Comment: @Tudor Is `volatile` preferred to `lock` in such a simple case?

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't that be a bit overkill in this case? There will be literally one, single member that needs to be switched as the thread ends. Please advise.

Comment: The word "overkill" is off the table when a call needs to be marshaled from one thread to another.  That's *hard* to do, it merely looks easy when you use BGW.

Comment: Well locks are not really useful here because boolean assignments are atomic anyway. All you need is visibility.

Comment: I'm shocked I didn't get "closed due to exact copy of..." - amazing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just set the `bool` to `false` as the last line in your thread (or as the last line before looping back to wait on something, if your thread does that).

Note @Tudor comment regarding `volatile` - just to be sure, do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backing store for your property to hold the value and use a `lock` whenever you set or get the value to ensure that no concurrency issue arises.
After that, when you start processing on a separate thread, set the value to `true` and before exiting the method set the value to `false`.

On user click just check the value of `KeepYourPantsOn` property and display the message if it is still `true`.

```
class YourClass
{
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
    private bool _keepYourPantsOn;

    public bool KeepYourPantsOn
    {
        get
        {
            lock(_syncRoot)
            {
                return _keepYourPantsOn;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock(_syncRoot)
            {
                _keepYourPantsOn = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private ThreadMethod()
    {
        KeepYourPantsOn = true; //signal that the update process is starting...
        // perform your logic
        KeepYourPantsOn = false; //signal that the update process is finished
    }

    public ManualUpdate()
    {
        if(KeepYourPantsOn)
            MessageBox.Show("Yes, yes... Updating still... Keep your pants on.");
        else
            Update();
    }
}
```